# Setting BoM type to set/phantom in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I would like to invoice BoM products and from what I've seen this is really easy in odoo 7.0 , where you can set BoM type to phantom/set. However, in the newest version (8.0 for windows) there are only two types of BoM : normal and set. Neither suits my needs. Do I need to activate something to get phantom functionality or was it deprecated in version 8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched that bundle option is unavailable in odoo 8.0, but you can create invoices for set components after ticking "invoice based on delivery" during a quotation creation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the BoM feature just add the manufacturing module ( Settings > Module > Local Modules, hit install - wait and and create group product by entering into the manufacturing module.

Comment: The thing about the BoM feature is that a BoM is exploded when "invoice based on delivery " ticked, however services do not generate delivery event so they are not included into the invoice, but thanks.